# Is there a way in a SQL language (pref T-SQL) to determine the position of a record in a set of consecutively ordered data for multiple records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So say for example, I have 2 tables with large data sets, one containing a list of users with their UserID.  Another table with their orders, which has an OrderNumber field-- a serial primary key incrementing as new orders are created, and a field with the UserID that placed the order.

These might look something like this:

```
USERS
-----
userid
1
2
3
4
5

ORDERS
-----
ordernumber          |               userid
1                    |                    1
2                    |                    2
3                    |                    1
4                    |                    1
5                    |                    3
6                    |                    1
7                    |                    2
```

Now, I have a list of Order Numbers that I need to find out the Order's position in chronological order (different than count) grouped by each order, and user.  Some users may have multiple orders in the list.

So input would be something like

```
ordernumber in (4, 5, 6, 7)
```

and based on all of the data above, it would return something like this where "accountsorder" is the position of the order in the accounts order history:

```
ordernumber          |        accountsorder
4                    |                    3
5                    |                    1
6                    |                    4
7                    |                    2
```

Let me know if I need to be more specific.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `row_number()` and subsequent filtering:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by ordernumber) as seqaccountsorder
      from orders o
     ) o
where ordernumber in (4, 5, 6, 7)
order by ordernumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say "chronological," then I think you definitely need to be referring to a date/time field within the `order` table.  You must never assume *any* particular "order" for rows in an SQL table:  you must `ORDER BY` *something.*